# How do I insert data via DBIx for Many to Many relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, orm, dbix-class

I am trying to get my head around DBiX and I’m struggling with how to insert data into my DB when I have a Many to Many relationship.

In my example below I have a Many to Many relationship between an Object and a Network.

An object has a Name and Description 
A Network has an IP and a Netmask

I have a junction table for the Many to Many relationship.

How do I add an Object and its associated network?

For example I have

```
object
—————
Name : TestObject1
Description: TestObject1
```

With the following Networks

```
IP:1.1.1.1
Netmask:255.255.255.255

IP:2.2.2.2
Netmask:255.255.255.255
```

AND

```
Name : TestObject2
Description: TestObject2
```

with the following Networks

```
IP:1.1.1.1
Netmask:255.255.255.255

IP:3.3.3.3
Netmask:255.255.255.255
```

I know how to insert data with 1 to Many relationships, but I can’t work out how to handle Many to Many.  Ideally I’d like to be able to build up my data structure and then just add it all in one go.

Below are the relevant tables which were created by the schema loader.

Thanks.

```
Object Table
------------

__PACKAGE__->table("Object");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "objectid",
  { data_type => "integer", is_auto_increment => 1, is_nullable => 0 },
  "description",
  { data_type => "varchar", is_nullable => 1, size => 100 },
  "objectname",
  { data_type => "varchar", is_nullable => 0, size => 100 },
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key("objectid");

__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "object_has_networks",
  "TestApp::Schema::Result::ObjectHasNetwork",
  { "foreign.object_objectid" => "self.objectid" },
  { cascade_copy => 0, cascade_delete => 0 },
);

__PACKAGE__->many_to_many(
  "network_networkids",
  "object_has_networks",
  "network_networkid",
);


 Network Table
 ------------

__PACKAGE__->table("network");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "networkid",
  { data_type => "integer", is_auto_increment => 1, is_nullable => 0 },
  “IP”,
  { data_type => "varchar", is_nullable => 1, size => 15 },
  "netmask",
  { data_type => "varchar", is_nullable => 1, size => 15 },
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key("networkid");

__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "object_has_networks",
  "TestApp::Schema::Result::ObjectHasNetwork",
  { "foreign.network_networkid" => "self.networkid" },
  { cascade_copy => 0, cascade_delete => 0 },
);
__PACKAGE__->many_to_many("object_objectids", "object_has_networks", "object_objectid");



Junction Table
--------------
__PACKAGE__->table("Object_has_network");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "object_objectid",
  { data_type => "integer", is_foreign_key => 1, is_nullable => 0 },
  "network_networkid",
  { data_type => "integer", is_foreign_key => 1, is_nullable => 0 },
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key("object_objectid", "network_networkid");:wq
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to(
  "network_networkid",
  "TestApp::Schema::Result::Network",
  { networkid => "network_networkid" },
  { is_deferrable => 1, on_delete => "NO ACTION", on_update => "NO ACTION" },
);

__PACKAGE__->belongs_to(
  "object_objectid",
  "TestApp::Schema::Result::Object",
  { objectid => "object_objectid" },
  { is_deferrable => 1, on_delete => "NO ACTION", on_update => "NO ACTION" },
);
```

Answer (score 2):

First DBIx is a whole namespace in which DBIx::Class is only a single dist. The common abbreviation is DBIC.

Many-to-many is not a relationship but a helper, so you just have to specify the two relations that form the m2m relationship bridge for searches and inserts.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. Looks like I have some more reading to do. I'm going to try some code and update this post with what I have tried. thanks.